# Trying to build WSO2 Governance Registry. Build getting failed

Tags: wso2

To build wso2 governance registry, I have build orbit and then all of its patch release and then kernel and its patch releases and while building platform I am getting build failure due to
"Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5:p2-profile-gen <3-p2-profile-generation> on project governance-profile-gen: P2 publisher return code was 13 "
so, its failing at P2 Profile Generation. Can any one Suggest me what exactly I need to do ?

Comment: which carbon version are you trying to build? 4.0.0 or 4.1.0? btw try building only the latest patch release.

Answer (score 0):

What's the version (patch version) you are trying to build when you get this error?

-Thilini

Comment: I got information from WSO2 saying that, I have to build platform root pom file before building the latest version. The same approach I followed even for Orbit and Kernel. I have checked out the code from carbon/trunk and the version is 4.0.5. So initially built 4.0.0 which is root and later built its patch releases for orbit and like wise for kernel and now trying to built 4.0.0 version of platform. So, Please clearly specify, how to build platform which makes the source code built for WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.3 ? Thanks !